# How to install apk on Emulator using Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to run apk on Emulator using Ubuntu, but facing problems, i have stored my apk to platform-tools

```
~/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools
```

but now when i am trying to install apk via command like this:

```
 system@sys02:~/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb install ChurchApp-2.7 Beta.apk
```

getting **can't find 'ChurchApp-2.7' to install**

Comment: there's a space in the filename, add single quotes around it.

Comment: Remove the space and rename the filename as Beta.apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally done, i used below command to run apk on Emulator

```
system@sys02:~/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb install ChurchApp-2.7.apk
```

**Note:-** don't forget to rename apk

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have a correct path to your ChurchApp (I don't think so it's under `sdk/platform-tools`). You should also escape the space in apk name:

```
$ ./adb install ChurchApp-2.7\ Beta.apk
```